# How to merge two rows of a HTML table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched in google but i don't find any solution of my issue.Could anyone tell me how to merge `Group` and `GPA/CGPA, Out of` rows?

For better view of my code see: **[BOOTPLY.](https://www.bootply.com/4dLEVlRKcs)**

What i want:

[image: SEE]

**This is my code, so far:**

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Level</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Name of Examination</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Year of Study</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Group /Subject</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Division/
        Class/Grade </th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2">Grade</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Board /University</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Year of Passing
        [yyyy]</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Result Published by Controller of Exam [dd/mm/yyyy]</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        SSC/Equivalent
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <th>GPA/CGPA</th>
      <th>Out of</th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        HSC/Equivalent
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        [CONTENT]
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Graduation
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Gradnoyear" id="Gradnoyear" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="38" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        [CONTENT]
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Post Graduation
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        [CONTENT]
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why just don't remove the border of the right, so it looks like is merged? :)

Comment: So, what do you mean by this merge? Do you want them both under the same column?

Comment: Could you tell me how can i do that?

Comment: @VladBalanescu yes i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to move your headings from the `tbody`, into the `theader` and then add a couple of normal columns to the `tbody` to replace the headings we just moved (comments in code as to what I have moved and added):

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Level</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Name of Examination</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Year of Study</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Group /Subject</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Division/ Class/Grade</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2">Grade</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Board /University</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Year of Passing [yyyy]
      </th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Result Published by Controller of Exam [dd/mm/yyyy]</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- put your other two headers from tbody here: -->
    <tr>
      <th>GPA/CGPA</th>
      <th>Out of</th>
    </tr>


  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        SSC/Equivalent
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>


    <!-- replace those headers we have moved with a couple of normal columns: -->

      <td>
        [CONTENT]
      </td>
      <td></td>


      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        HSC/Equivalent
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        [CONTENT]
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Graduation
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Gradnoyear" id="Gradnoyear" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="38" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        [CONTENT]
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Post Graduation
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSC" id="cboSSC" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="21" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
          <option value="Dakhil">Dakhil</option>
          <option value="O Level">O Level</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCGroupSubject" id="cboSSCGroupSubject" class="breadcrumbSmall1" tabindex="22" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Science">Science</option>
          <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
          <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
          <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
          <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="cboSSCResult" id="cboSSCResult" class="breadcrumbcombo1" tabindex="23" onchange="setCGPA('SSC');" style="visibility: visible;">
          <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
          <option value="Third">Third</option>
          <option value="Grade">Grade</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        [CONTENT]
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCBoard" id="txtSSCBoard" class="SL2TextField" tabindex="26" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="4" name="txtGradYear" id="txtGradYear" class="SLNumFieldSmall" onkeypress="return keypressOnNumberFld_new(event)" tabindex="43" value="" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtSSCResYear" id="txtSSCResYear" class="SLNumFieldMed" tabindex="28" value="" onkeydown="keypressOnDateFld();" maxlength="10" onblur="MyvalidDate(document.getElementById('txtSSCResYear').value,'txtSSCResYear')">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/aRfVHZRoYw)

Comment: Yes! This is what i am looking for : )